# How to do fsync() in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on a project related to databases in C#. After each transaction commit, I want the db to move all the buffered data onto disk. In Linux, fflush() + fsync() would provide what I want. To get the same effect, what should I do in C#?

Comment: How is the data buffered? Is it in a FileStream, for example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method corresponding to C' `fflush()` is `Flush()` of [FileStream class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bw4h516%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Anyway, this is related to files, not to databases.

**EDIT**
If you are targeting 4.0 .NET Framework, there's a [new overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee474552.aspx) that accepts a boolean. According to its description:

```
Flush(bool flushToDisk)
```

> flushToDisk
>   Type: System.Boolean
>   true to flush all intermediate file buffers; otherwise, false.

you should invoke it passing `true`.

Comment: I'm actually writing a database in C#.. There is also Flush(Boolean). (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.flush.aspx) I'm not sure which one I should use.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, when working with something like SQL Server, you don't have control over *when* the database writes data to disk.

All you should worry about is ensuring the `commit` of your transaction is successful.

Which database server are you using?